# dropdown on change scroll to specific id

Tags: jquery

I have an Dropdown with more than 100 option. I want to scroll to div when selecting option to same id matching with option value. any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<select>
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Comment: Try this link now http://jsfiddle.net/6Em4H/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + $(this).val()).position().top });
});
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/gcXM7/1/

Though, in case it's not obvious, you might want to give your select an id

```
<select id="foo">
```

and select only that one

```
$('#foo').on('change', ...
```

Comment: Ok. Do you understand what it's doing and if not do you want me to add an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Hey check this you need describe id of your dropdown first check this fiddle code

Html

```
<select id="divselector">
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('#divselector').change(function(){
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#'+$('#divselector').val()).offset().top}, 'slow'); 
     })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id='test'>
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="a" style="position:absolute; top:100px;">a div</div>
<div id="b" style="position:absolute; top:200px;">b div</div>
<div id="c" style="position:absolute; top:500px;">c div</div>



 $('select#test').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#'+val).offset().top }, 0)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crQu9/1/